# python selenium error stale element: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get all data from a website called Correios, in this website, I need to handle some dropdowns which I'm having some issues like: It don't get all values from the first dropbox info.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select


chrome_path = r"C:\\Users\\Gustavo\\Desktop\\geckodriver\\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
lista_x = []
driver.get("http://www2.correios.com.br/sistemas/agencias/")
driver.maximize_window()

estado_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('estadoAgencia'))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'municipioAgencia')))
municipio_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('municipioAgencia'))
for opt in estado_select.options:
    print(opt.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
    opt.click()
    for opt2 in municipio_select.options:
        print(opt.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
        opt2.click()

driver.close()
```

Sometimes my code run OK, but sometimes it gives me this error:

```
ACRE
ACRE
ALAGOAS
ALAGOAS
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gustavo\Desktop\insper\trabalho\Correios3.py", line 23, in <module>
    opt2.click()
  File "C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

What should I do?

Comment: still gets the same error, i'm going to put the new code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the traceback, the excepting is thrown from `opt2.click`. I guess that whenever you select an option from the estados drop-down, the available options in the municipio drop-down are updated accordingly. This means that the options that you get from `municipio_select.options` after selecting the 2nd estado are no longer valid and that's why you get that exception.

In order to solve that, move the line:
`municipio_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('municipioAgencia'))`
to after `opt.click()` (inside the outer loop, just before the inner for loop). This will cause the inner loop to iterate over the *updated* list of municipio options, and should resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume `estado_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('estadoAgencia'))` returns 2 links.
You then iterate through the urls `estado_select`. During first iteration, (`opt` contains to first link), when you do `opt.click()`, you browser loads a new page and so the second link is now stale. So during second iteration `opt.click` would fail and generate the error `StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

You have to do `driver.navigate().back()` after each `click` or you have to parse the new page again and build `estado_select` and `municipio_select` again

Comment: but both dropdowns are in the same page, the URL never changes

Comment: Even if the URL never changes, visibility of elements can change. You might hit this issue if the second link has now become invisible